# Value of C of a bivariate discrete distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have the following math problem:

$ \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}  C/(i*j)^2 = 1 $

where C is the value of the constant that makes this function be equal to 1.

I am not being able to find how to prove this converge and prove how C goes to $ 36/pi^4 $

Answer (score 2):

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {i^{2}}=\frac {\pi^{2}} 6$. The given equation is $C \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {i^{2}j^{2}}=1$. You can sum w.r.t. $i$ first and then w.r.t. $j$.  When you sum w.r.t. $i$, $\frac  1{j^{2}}$ comes out of the summation so you get $C\frac {\pi^{2}} 6 \frac {\pi^{2}} 6=1$.

Comment: where does the value pi^2/6 come from?

Comment: @Gustavomoty it is a well known fact that $\sum \frac 1 {i^{2}}=\pi^{2}/6$. This fact is required to answer this question. The fact that the answer involves $\pi$ suggests that you are suppose to know this fact. You can  prove convergence of the series by integral test but getting the exact value of the sum requires a deeper analysis.

Comment: An original proof for Euler series can be found [there](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/EulerSeries.shtml)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for this comment.

Comment: thanks you guys!

Comment: @Gustavomoty Please don´t forget to accept ($\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}$) this answer. I give you this information since you are a new member here at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ two times. You will get the answer.